# What is the First&Only TOE after Salvation Reach book?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I was wondering what is the TOE of the *Gaunt's Ghosts* regiment after the *Salvation Reach* book. What I know so far.

- Hark, Ludd, Blennner and Fariaka (?) are all commissars attached to the regiment
- Kolea, Bask, Rawne and Pasha are all majors
- Daur, Criid, Merryn, Obel, Kolosim and Domor are Captains
- Wilder is a Captain of the colours band (young brother of the second commander of ghosts)

So how many companies are there total and what is the chain of command?

[image: Chart of command]

Lexicanum is a bit outdated and that is why I'm asking so please no link only answers or links to lexicanum to the Tanith first and only stub.

### TOE AFTER WARMASTER

[image: Chart of command after Warmaster]

TOE AFTER WARMASTER  (Red names are uncredited and id like confirmation if possible).
Also 4 companies will have new leadership after Warmaster

[image: Chart of command after Warmaster]

Comment: Gaunt is the Colonel-Comissar through all of the books I believe?

Comment: Yes he is. From the first book and onwards he is a dual beast, a Colonel-commissar. He is the Commander of the Ghosts in all books but 2. Wilder takes over when Gaunt goes on a suicide mission.

Comment: Theory of Everything?

Comment: Gaunt is no longer Colonel at the end of Warmaster - he gets promoted. Twice.

Comment: @Yasskier oh snap... ye true... Makes B Company leaderless then... Bugger! also C company might or might not be leaderless depending on the next book!

Comment: If you're gonna use an acronym, make sure it's one people actually know. I've never seen TOE used before, so I suspect not many outside of the military would recognize it.

Answer (score 4):

Per *Warmaster:*

There are two promotions that I don’t want to mention here because they spoil the novel. Most of the promotions I mention below, as well as the commands assigned, are actually shown in novels prior to *Warmaster.*

The Tanith first consist of 20 companies, numbering over 5,000 Guardsmen (pg. 539, eBook)

The list of Companies goes all the way to V, with that letter being assigned to the Colours Company (which includes the Belladon band, under Captain Wilde, etc.; pg 500, eBook). At risk of sounding obvious, as V is the 20th letter of the English alphabet, we can infer that the 20 companies of the regiment are A-V, with no gaps in between and no companies designated W-Z. This structure does not include the Scout cadre, of course.

Baskevyl and Kolea are Majors (pg. 242, eBook)

Fazekiel should be added to the list of Comissars (pg. 231, eBook)

Major Yve “Pasha” Petrushkevskaya commands more than one company (pg. 231); interestingly, she is nonetheless not considered senior to Baskevyl, Kolea, or Rawne. I’d rather not touch this one for a little while, though, due to spoiler considerations.

Elam (rank unspecified in *Warmaster)* leads an unspecified company (pg. 167, eBook). I list him above the named captains because he *might* be a major based on conversations regarding potential promotions (pg. 391). On the other hand, Ban Daur is also included in said conversations, and he’s a captain.

A Company is Gaunt’s own company. In the opening action of the novel, he makes Tona Criid’s promotion official and gives her command of said company (pg. 116, eBook)

Company G is commanded by Captain Ban Daur (pg. 465, eBook)

Company K is commanded by Captain Shoggy Domor (pg. 166, eBook)

There is a Captain MKlure, with no specified command (pg. 270, eBook)

Captain Nico Spetnin is mentioned as a candidate for company command (pg. 368, eBook)

Arcuda (pg. 158, eBook) is a company commander without specified rank; his company is not named.

As I get further into the novel, I’ll add more data and page numbers and citations for promotions that predate it. Again, some stuff shouldn’t be included in this topic for another couple of weeks, to give people a chance to read it without plot points (however major or minor) being spoiled.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good start, but providing some sources would really help boost your answer, snippets from the relevant texts would be good!

Comment: Welcome to the site. To expand on Edlothiad's advice, specifying where in *Warmaster* you found that info would make this a much better answer.

Comment: @Φοίβος  Elam is indeed a Major. It is the first name of Rawne and he is Commanding officer of B Company.  Im sure Arcuda's company got mentioned in "Salvations Reach". This leaves Major Pashas command company vacant and the 3 Captains that are still not fixed to a company.
There are also 3 companies Pasha brings with her so there are potentially 3 more Captains there... Hope Warmaster can shed some light into this... Im Sure Arcuda is lead of either F or I Companies as he is senior.... HELP still needed!!

Comment: @Φοίβος as for Pasha... Yes she is a Major and she did bring 3 companies with her as part of the influx but that does NOT make her senior to Rawne, Gol or Bask. All of those tough guys have been with the Tanith command for a lot longer than Pasha and that is how seniority works in any army or military unit... Rawne is XO of the company and both him and the other Majors sometime lead parts of the regiment as their personal sections ( as shown in Salvation Reach and countles other novels)

Comment: @Cherubel, **Elam** is a separate character. You’re thinking of **Elim** Rawne. As for Pasha, I didn’t say that she was superior to those others. My intent was to point out it was interesting that she nonetheless had three companies under her command.

Comment: As i stated Pasha is part of the influx that came to the Ghosts just before the action on Salvation Reach (if i remember correct most female). 3 companies were raised and you cant have a captain command 3 companies so... enter Major Pasha. The only interesting part (pervious to Warmaster) is that she is a female.

Comment: @cherubael, with respect, I’m well aware of Pasha’s origins and rank. The point I’m bringing up is that she’s the only major in the regiment specified as commanding multiple companies. To my knowledge, it has never been qualified why this is.

Comment: maybe a language barrrier here.. dunno. As i wrote before most other majors and sometimes even Captains take over overall command over parts of the regiment when in theatre. Last seen in Salvations Reach but also in Warmaster (when the action finally starts). Pasha commands only 1 company, her own (as yet not named). Her rank gives her the option to command more than one company. nothing strange.

Comment: It might be that it is the wording in the books that is confusing or interpretation. If she is present and Domors, Criids and Arcudas companies are in the same vicinity that Pasha is attacking/defending than Pasha is overall commander and in charge. Same applies for any other Major.

Comment: This is what I’m referencing:

““Major Pasha too,’ said Kolea.
Fazekiel nodded. ‘I gather Spetnin and Zhukova are crestfallen. They were just getting used to running Pasha’s companies.”

Excerpt From
The Warmaster
Dan Abnett
https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-warmaster/id1317692679?mt=11
This material may be protected by copyright.”

I don’t know which part of the novel you’re citing, but to me the above clearly indicates Pasha has ongoing command of multiple companies - not just temporary control over them during a battle. That has not been the case with any other Major.

Answer (score 1):

Per the list of promotions in the short story 'This Is What Victory Feels Like', there are some interesting, albeit confusing, changes:

Ban Daur is referred to as being in command of D Company, whereas in several previous novels, most prominently His Last Command, the Armour of Contempt and Only In Death, he commands G Company. It has been a while since i have read the novels but i was under the impression that Major Baskevyl commanded D Company.

Another confusion is the total lack of a mention of Captain Jan Sloman, who has been featured quite regularly and isn't included among the officers present during the promotion meeting.

One final point i have had trouble getting my head around is that the Tanith First is quoted as being twenty companies strong, yet they supposedly have Companies A through to V, with V being the 22nd letter of the alphabet, and T the twentieth. Perhaps V Company isn't included in the twenty 'fighting' companies, as it is the colours band of the Regiment.

Comment: The 2 diagrams in the question don't list a "Q" company, so that makes 20 companies (A-P, R-U) plus V as the colours company.  Given the change in command of "D" company, does this fit in the time frame requested in the question?

Comment: Not sure why there wouldn't be a Q Company though? Why skip a letter? My guess upon re-reading the aforementioned short story is that G and D have been mixed up by Abnett

Answer (score 0):

Arcuda commands N Company, its mentioned in Only In Death. Also, who is Kirya? and Vivvo isn't a Captain, he's Captain Daur's second, who is away with Gaunt meeting Macaroth, and so takes command of G Company.

Comment: Hi there! :) could you [edit] in elements from the lore works to back up your point, such as quotes? This would make for a clearer, and greater, answer. As for Kirya, I'm not sure what you mean as of now - if you have a specific question, you can ask it with the "Ask question" button; see [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Kirya is a name i saw on the fandom page. a lot of the "red names" are also doubtfull as some of those might be dead or cited as wrong companies. ex Sabreese. on some sites he is cited as comander of A company and other sites have him lead a different company. Criid is A comander and this i know for a fact. If you can quote from the books that Vivvo isnt a saptain and that Arcuda is N commander i will change it. Thanks for bringing arcuda up. After lookind at the 3rd revision i can see that Arcuda isnt on the list. I love that guy and i taught he got killed off at some point.